# Driver not found exception JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I keep getting the next exception when connecting to the database from eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at connection.ConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionFactory.java:29)
    at connection.ConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ConnectionFactory.java:25)
    at dao.StudentDAO.insert(StudentDAO.java:53)
    at bll.StudentBLL.insertStudent(StudentBLL.java:39)
    at start.Start.main(Start.java:23)
```

However, the connection is established, I can read from the database, I can write in it but the exception does not disappear.
I have added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin  to the path file with build path, and appears at the library section.
 I believe the URL, user and password are correctly written, since I can write in the DB. 
Connection is established by :

```
   try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localHost:3306/schooldb","root","");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "An error occured while trying to connect to the database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

The code for the Driver is:

```
  private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am working with eclipse Oxygen, in a Maven Project.
The database is created with MYSQLWorkbench 6.0CE.

But I have not idea what is wrong with the Driver.

Comment: localhost is written with a capital H in the connection string, could this be the problem? also not sure if jdbc accepts an empty string for the password

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: "However, the connection is established..." Not if you get a `ClassCastException`. What makes you think that you have a connection? The exception should stop your code there and then, unless you have a `catch(Exception ex)` somewhere high up in your code. Also, you should be getting something like "no suitable driver found for URL..." instead of a `ClassCastException`, which means you're doing a `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` somewhere, which you don't need since Java 1.6.

Comment: I have tried inserting into the database and printing what i have in the database(checked with the db too) so I assumed that since both  were working the connection was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your driver name is incorrect
Here is the driver i use, try it

> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

also make 'H' in local host lowercase

If the solution above doesnt work:

1: remove import `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.*`
2: Use this driver `private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";`

Comment: Domain names, including `localhost`, are case-insensitive. So that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, you were correct I had the driver name wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45 driver, which uses the driver class name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, but try to load the driver class name introduced in the new MySQL Connector/J 8.x driver.

Either upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 8.0.11 (available at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), or - if you want to keep using 5.1.45 for now - use

```
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

As an aside, for backwards compatibility, MySQL Connector/J 8.x also retains above class for loading.

Technically, loading the driver like this isn't even necessary in a lot of situations due to JDBC 4 and higher automatic driver loading.